# How to write a generic service in spring boot which will map DTO to Model and Model to DTO?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am developing an e-commerce rest api using spring boot and I have more than ten models and DTOs classes in my project, so I do not want to write in each service functions which map to Enitity and Dto. Is it possible to use a generic interface that will be like a service in which I can write model mapping logic and then I use it in every service?

**Here is what I am doing in each service:**

```
@Resource(name = "modelMapper")
private final ModelMapper modelMapper;
```

```
private FaqDto mapToDto(Faq faq){
    FaqDto faqDto = modelMapper.map(faq, FaqDto.class);
    return faqDto;
}
//map to entity
private Faq mapToEntity(FaqDto faqDto){
    Faq faq = modelMapper.map(faqDto, Faq.class);
    return faq;
}
```

**And here what I am trying to do:**

```
public interface CommonService<T> {

   //entity mapper
   T mapToEntity(T type);

   //dto mapper
   T mapToDto(T type);
}
```

```
@Service
@Slf4j
@AllArgsConstructor
@Component("commonService")
public class CommonServiceImpl implements CommonService{

   private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CommonServiceImpl.class);

   @Resource(name = "modelMapper")
   private final ModelMapper modelMapper;

   
   @Override
    public Object mapToEntity(Object type) {
        Object entityObject = modelMapper.map(type, Object.class);
        return entityObject;
    }

   @Override
    public Object mapToDto(Object type) {
        Object dtoObject = modelMapper.map(type, Object.class);
        return dtoObject;
    }
}
```

**Once I inject this CommonService in other services and trying to use it, so I have to use type casting but still getting error at Postman.**

Comment: check here please : https://www.baeldung.com/entity-to-and-from-dto-for-a-java-spring-application

Comment: I already use an approach like that one but I want to change it to a global service by using java generics and then use this service everywhere in the project instead of rewriting converter methods every time.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to create some generic methods, you should create an abstract class to extends in every service.

To start you should add two types to your CommonService

```java
// E for Entity and D for DTO
public interface CommonService<E, D> {

    //entity mapper
    E mapToEntity(D type);

    //dto mapper
    D mapToDto(E type);

}
```

And create a `AbstractCommonService` that implements those methods :

```java
public class AbstractCommonService<E, D> implements CommonService<E, D>{

    protected final ModelMapper modelMapper;
    private final Class<E> entityClass;
    private final Class<D> dtoClass;

    public AbstractCommonService(ModelMapper modelMapper, Class<E> entityClass, Class<D> dtoClass) {
        this.modelMapper = modelMapper;
        this.entityClass = entityClass;
        this.dtoClass = dtoClass;
    }


    @Override
    public E mapToEntity(D type) {
        E entityObject = modelMapper.map(type, entityClass);
        return entityObject;
    }

    @Override
    public D mapToDto(E type) {
        D dtoObject  = modelMapper.map(type, dtoClass);
        return dtoObject ;
    }
}
```

And create your specific service this way :

```java
@Service
@Slf4j
@Component("specificService")
public class SpecificService extends AbstractCommonService<SpecificEntity, SpecificDto> {

    public SpecificService(ModelMapper modelMapper) {
        super(modelMapper, SpecificEntity.class, SpecificDto.class);
    }

    public void testMethod() {
        this.mapToEntity(new SpecificDto());
    }

}
```

This way you can have only one function to map your entity and your dto for all your services.

Comment: I follow those steps and implemented them but I got an exception saying that the destination type is null: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: destinationType cannot be null